# Playing the key value on keydown in C#

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, keydown

I'm quite new to C# and am working on developing a software for blind and visually impaired people.
in the software I want to have a text box that when a key is pressed it will make a
sound for instance when pressing j it will say j...
I found the wonderful text to speech engine and tried using it with the keydown event as follows:

```
   SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();            
   char mappedChar = (char)e.KeyValue;       
   synth.Speak(Convert.ToString(mappedChar));
   synth.Dispose();
```

unfortunately it is way too slow and takes approx. 1 second between each key stroke.

Would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start by not creating and disposing of your `SpeechSynthesizer` object in the event handler.

Create the object once when the program runs and just have:

```
char mappedChar = (char)e.KeyValue;       
synth.Speak(mappedChar.ToString());
```

in your event handler.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but the improvement was tiny and not enugh. There is still a consdirable delay. Is there anything else I can do about it?

Comment: @me1982 - that's odd, I would have thought that it would have made a bigger difference.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the constructor of speechsynthesizer is taking most of the time. Try creating the synth object once and caching it, rather than creating it on each call.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new SpeechSynthesizer instance is expensive.

Define your synth object as a member of the form, instantiate it that scope, then just refer to it in your event code. e.g. in pseudo code...

```
class MyForm
{
  SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer(); 
  ...

  void On_Click(<params>)
  {
     this.synth.Speak(<text>);
  }

}
```